# Linking/Re-Indexing Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a Main Array which has multiple arrays inside. What I'm trying to achieve is to link/add/push them to their upper/main array

```
Array
(
    [dates] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-02-28
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-03-03
                )

        )

    [times] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [start_time] => 17:30
                            [end_time] => 19:30
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [start_time] => 19:30
                            [end_time] => 21:30
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [start_time] => 21:30
                            [end_time] => 23:30
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [start_time] => 23:30
                            [end_time] => 01:30
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [start_time] => 14:00
                            [end_time] => 14:30
                        )

                )

        )

    [streamers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [username] => usernamehere
                            [name] => namehere
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Arrays under times[0] have to be linked/added to dates[0] and users[0] haveto be linked/added to dates[0]

I tried array_merge and array_push but I've never worked with something like this before so any help will be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you print_r instead of var_dump please ? (easier to read) and how do you want it to merge ? Let's say I put times[0] into dates[0] : Is it by appending ? Or merging the objects ?

I will try this meanwhile (appending) :

```
foreach ($big_array as $key1 => $array) {
    if ($key1 == 'times') {
        //Insert times into dates
        foreach ($array as $key2 => $val) {
           array_push($big_array['dates'][$key2],$val);
        }
    } else if ($key1 == 'users') {
        //Insert users into dates
        foreach ($array as $key2 => $val) {
           array_push($big_array['dates'][$key2],$val);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE : You don't need to do 2 if, only 1 is enough (this is only for readability)

Answer (score 0):

With BabyAzerty's help I tried this :

```
            foreach ($streams as $key1 => $array) {

                if ($key1 == 'times') {
                    //Insert times into dates
                    foreach ($array as $key2 => $val) {
                    //array has objects so I had to add this line
                        $test[] = $streams['dates'][$key2];
                        array_push((array)$test, (array)$val);
                    }
                } else if ($key1 == 'streamers') {
                    //Insert users into dates
                    foreach ($array as $key2 => $val) {
                        //var_dump($streams['times']);
                        //array_push($test, $val);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The output without adding users is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-02-28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 17:30
                    [end_time] => 19:30
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 19:30
                    [end_time] => 21:30
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 21:30
                    [end_time] => 23:30
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 23:30
                    [end_time] => 01:30
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-03-03
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 14:00
                    [end_time] => 14:30
                )

        )

)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is :

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-02-28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 17:30
                    [end_time] => 19:30
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 19:30
                    [end_time] => 21:30
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 21:30
                    [end_time] => 23:30
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 23:30
                    [end_time] => 01:30
                )

        )
  )

 [1] => Array
  (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-03-03
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start_time] => 14:00
                    [end_time] => 14:30
                )
        )
   )

)
```

Thanks!